# why search function in JDBC is not working in my code?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new in JDBC. I am trying to search data form database. but it's not working into my code. when i try to search firstname in search box then nothing displays. please help!!. I am using netbeans 8.2, Apache tomcat 8, xampp MySQL.

This is my JDBC code

```
      Connection con = null;
      PreparedStatement ps = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;

      con = DB.getConnection();
      String sql = "select * from newfiles";
      ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      String query = request.getParameter("search"); 
      String data;
      if(query != null){
          data = "select * from newfiles where 2='%"+query+"%'";
      }
      else{
          data = "select * from newfiles order by 1 desc";
      }
      rs = stmt.executeQuery(data);
      while(rs.next()){
```

Comment: That looks like an invalid while loop. You sure there is nothing being displayed including errors?

Comment: no errors are there. but not search from my database

Comment: only "else" part is executing. "if" part is not executing

Comment: because your "request.getParameter("search"); " code is returning null, and writing database code in jsp is not good, try to move that code to the server side and from there render the data to JSP using JSTL library.

Comment: @ShankarSaranSingh can you please tell me what changes should I do at "request.getParameter("search"); "

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIydwBcd9NM  I have taken reference from this you tube video

Comment: I also refereer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4D1TVGd7UA

Comment: please help....

Comment: Side note: never EVER use string concatenation to create SQL commands from user input, not even in a school project. This makes your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead.

Comment: The condition `2='%"+query+"%'"` looks suspicious as the string literal `'%<something>%'` will **never** be equal to the integer `2`, maybe you meant `like` instead of `=`, in addition using this comparison against an integer is likely not what you meant, maybe you need to use a column name instead of `2`. And as Jozef said: never ever concatenate values into a query string.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Thank you so much. I used column name instead of integer and I replaced "=" with "like". problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Where comes your parameter "search" from? Are you sending it from a previous page, right? I suppose you are trying to search for a string the user wrote in a textbox named "search" in a form. First read about MVC. Use your first page to send data to the server side. Get it in the POST method from servlet and make a database connection also on the server side. Get the results from your database query and send only the results to the next page filelist.jsp. Use jstl (maven: [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl]) to display the results.

Comment: my issue is solved. Thanks to all for your response and time.

Comment: I used "like" instead of "="